# Windows Powershell Text is not visible

Tags: node.js, powershell, cmd

In my windows powershell sometimes some text does not appears, if I run those commands in command prompt then the text is visible.
I tried changing background and text colors but the problem still exists.

What things to do to make text visible?

{I have installed npm module faker to generate some random details and I am outputting those details using console.log() in app.js }

[image: Power shell screenshot]

[image: cmd screenshot]

Comment: This probably has to do with your [PowerShell profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7#the-noprofile-parameter), try: `PowerShell -NoProfile`

Comment: still got same output

Comment: If that does not work try `cmd /c "cd 'Directory of app.js' & node app.js` on powershell console.

Comment: I would assume that the results come back complete with ANSI codes, node intercepts them and converts to one of 16 colors. As there are a lot more that 16 colors, it has to choose a similar/nearest one if the stated color is not one of those 16. It unfortunately chhoses one which matches that of your Powershell window's background colour.

Comment: You said that you've tried changing the colors, perhaps you could try changing your Powershell console font, to see if it helps.